# Separating an address string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a table called `Houses` on an sql server database that has a column containing (Danish) addresses. In Denmark the street name always comes before the house number and then the apartment information if it's an apartment. I want to separate the street name and the number into two strings and disregard the apartment information. My data looks like this:

```
Address
Fisker Vejen 48B, 1.TV
Baunevej 29
```

Thus, some street names have more than 1 word, and some adresses have apartment information and some don't. Some house numbers have non-numeric characters as well. I want it to be:

```
Street_Name      House_Number
Fisker Vejen     48B
Baunevej         29
```

I am able to extract the street name with the following code:

```
select case when a.NumStart> 0 then LEFT(a.Address,a.NumStart-1) ELSE a.Address END as Street_Name,
    FROM
    (select patindex('%[0-9]%',Address) as [NumStart], Address from Houses) a
```

but I can't get the house number without the floor information. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: The **','** will always be between street number and apartment information?

Comment: Yes, but the street number might contain a non-numeric character as well. I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT *
        ,LEFT(Address,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address)-1)'Street'
        , SUBSTRING(Address,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address)+1,PATINDEX('%[0-9],%',Address+ ',')-PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address))'House Number'
FROM T
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac3cc/1/0)

UPDATE:  If house number always starts with numbers and is followed by a comma or nothing at all, then this will work:

```
SELECT *
        ,LEFT(Address,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address)-1)'Street'
        , SUBSTRING(Address,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address)+1,PATINDEX('%, %',Address+ ', ')-PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',Address)-1)'House Number'
FROM Table1
```

Demo2: [SQL Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1735/4/0)

Comment: It almost works. It's not quite generic enough since the address could be `Fisker Vejen 48B, 1.TV` and I would want the number to be `48B`.

Comment: Updated to accommodate, if it's still too rigid you might need case logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN  a.NumStart> 0 then LEFT(a.Adresse, a.NumStart-1) ELSE a.Adresse END as Vejnavn,
  Substring(a.adress, a.Numstart, a.Comma - a.Numstart + 1) as HouseNumber
FROM (
  SELECT 
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Adress) as [NumStart], 
    CHARINDEX(',', Adress + ',') as Comma,
    Adresse, 
    Salgsdato 
  FROM Houses) a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  Vejnavn, 
  case when NumEnd > 0 then left(rest,NumEnd-1) else rest end Housenumber 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    *, 
    patindex('%[^0-9A-Z]%',rest) numend 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN a.NumStart> 0 THEN LEFT(a.Adresse,a.NumStart-1) ELSE a.Adresse END as Vejnavn,
      CASE WHEN a.NumStart> 0 THEN SUBSTRING(a.Adresse,a.NumStart,100) ELSE '' END rest
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Adresse) AS [NumStart], 
        Adresse 
      FROM Houses
    ) a
   ) b 
 ) c
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bea1/1)

Comment: My example was flawed since I forgot to mention that the house numbers could contain non-numeric characters, such as `48B` and in this case I want the number to be `48B` and not `48`.

Comment: Edited to pick up letters as well